# JDateChooser drag and drop doesn't work on IntelliJ macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, drag-and-drop, jdatechooser

I was trying to drag and drop a component "JDateChooser" on my JDialog but It wasn't working at all. All the others component works but not the JDateChooser.

The component is used from the "jcalendar-1.4" jar library.

My solution to this is to declare a JPanel where the component should be and add the component "JDatecChooser" in the JPanel.

```java
private JPanel JPanelDateNaissance;
private JDateChooser JDateChooser1;


 public JDialogInscription() {
        JDateChooser1 = new JDateChooser();
        JPanelDateNaissance.add(JDateChooser1);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);
....
```

Hope this will be useful !